# OnClientClick event handler not called if using onclick

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with templatefield. I put a Linkbutton in templatefield.
I want show popup window and update db when linkbutton is click .
I use the following code

```
<asp:LinkButton onclick="LinkButton-click" onclientclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowModalDialog({url:''}; return true;)." runnat="serevr" />
```

but popup Window opens and is closed after a few moments

Answer (score 1):

Use hyperlink `<a href=""/>` instead of `<asp:LinkButton/>` server control because `LinkButton` does postback. Specify `return false;` might work.

```
 <asp:LinkButton 
    ID="linkButton1" 
    runat="server" 
    Text="Something"
    OnClientClick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowModalDialog({url:''}); return false;">
 </asp:LinkButton>
```

To handle click event at server-side of LinkButton in GridView, you have to use events of GridView control. for instance - `RowCommand`.

Comment: RowCommand is GridView event. If you have any question regarding to RowCommand then update your post with relevant code and problem description. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Comment: When i use OnClientClick in LinkButton , RowCommand don't run .

Comment: @niloo - You should try two buttons - one to open Modaldialog(client) and other to perform server-side code.

Comment: I have a linkbutton, i don't use two linkbutton.

Comment: Remove OnClientClick or return true. I think you have to use jQuery/Ajax through which you can  perform both client code execution and server-code execution.

Comment: I want show popup window and update db when linkbutton is click . When i remove onclientclick or return true , popup window not open!